# How does gdb detect pthread?

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads

Recently I've been learning about pthread. Then I suddenly came out of an idea that how does gdb know I create a new thread. Then I wrote down a test code below and started up gdb. I step into pthread_create() function, but instead of letting it return normally, I use `return 0` to return pthread_create() function. But gdb still shows that I have only one thread. At first, I thought that gdb got thread information from the return value from the pthread_create() function then I thought gdb might also use child process info to the get thread info so I edited my test code. But the result wasn't what I thought of.

So how does gdb get thread info? What kind of information it needs to know how many threads the main thread have and which thread I'm on.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pthread.h"

void *foo(void *bar) {
        while(1) {
                printf("hello from thread: %d\n", pthread_self());
                sleep(2);
        }
}

int main() {
        printf("Before fake pthread_create");
        pid_t pid;
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
                perror("fork error");
                exit(errno);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
                while(1) {

                        sleep(3);
                }
        }

        if (pid > 0) {

                pthread_t thread;
                pthread_create(&thread, NULL, foo, NULL);
                while(1) {
                        printf("hello from thread: %d\n", pthread_self());
                        sleep(2);
                }
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: for all practical purposes, set a break point on the first line of the thread function

Answer (score 2):

> How does gdb detect pthread?

GDB sets internal breakpoint on `_dl_debug_state`, which allows it track which shared libraries are loaded (this is necessary for debugging shared libraries).

When it observes that `libpthread.so` is loaded, it loads `libthread_db.so.1` into *its own* process space (into GDB itself, not into the program being debugged), and asks that library to notify GDB when new threads are created and when they are destroyed. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54772/libc-db-3lib.html#REFMAN3Flibc-db-3lib).

The `libthread_db` has intimate knowledge of the internals of `libpthread`, and installs appropriate hooks to achieve such notification.

Comment: Except of course for static programs that don't load libthread_db.so.1, such as many of those written in R by default.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 main mechanisms that debuggers use on linux, and neither of them are very pretty. There is so much detail here that I can only point you there and hope.

One is ptrace which allows the debugger to follow along as the program does things, such as executing system commands like `pthread_create`, or specific events happen, such as new threads starting, and control the monitored program: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html

The other is the /proc/ file system which reveals lots of information about a process: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

In particular `ls -l /proc/self/tasks` shows you what threads `ls` has (only 1).

Comment: GDB uses `libthread_db`, which is *neither* of the mechanisms you listed.

Comment: True, but internally libthread_db, the user-side library, uses a number of mechanisms including, on linux at least, ptrace and /proc/ as well as its own secret helper threads. But yes, thanks for reminding me about libthread_db.